# Nikon D3100 & Speedlite question

Tags: nikon, hotshoe-flash

I have a Nikon D3100, & a YN560II Speedlite. Sometimes when I want to use my speedlite, the auto flash will pop up when I take a photo. I know I've not done something right in my setting, can someone help me.

Comment: Duplicate question:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/why-is-the-on-camera-flash-trying-to-pop-up-when-using-a-d7000-with-a-mk930-spee?rq=1

Comment: We need more information to help you. Is the YN-560II on the hotshoe? Have you inspected the camera hotshoe for obstructions? Are you trying to use the flash off-camera? If so, how are you triggering it? (i.e., what slave mode is the YN-560II in? And what are you doing with the camera to trigger the flash [commander mode? radio trigger?]).

Comment: @MikeSowsun, not sure that's actually a good answer, given that the flash hotshoe _should_ have a physical switch in the rails that's engaged when any speedlight is mounted and this switch tells the camera NOT to pop up the built-in flash--has nothing to do with TTL/CLS signals. A YN-560 or other manual-only flash works fine on most hotshoes, can't see Nikon's being an exception here.

Comment: I must have fixed it w/ my settings,  I put the speedlite back on the camera mount,  turned it on, tested a shot & the camera flash did not pop up as it did yesterday.  I'm using the M setting on my Nikon, my speedlite is set to the M & using 1/16 power. @ 50MM.  Using a Nikon 50mm  lens, however this has also been happening with my test shots, no matter where I aim the camera, the flash is only picking up the very top portion of the picture, the remaining 95 % of the picture is black.  any suggestions what I might be doing wrong. I've used this speedlite several times before,albeit nt a lot

Comment: @JaniceButler Check your shutter speed: see [What does an unexposed band on your image mean?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76797/), or ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @inkista - Sounds like you need to write an answer to the other question that this one duplicates. We may also have a question about how to fix a hot shoe when the rail switch fails to close properly (due to looseness in the rails).

Comment: @MichaelClark Closest I can find is [this one](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/i-cannot-open-the-internal-flash-on-my-canon-60d-camera-how-do-i-fix-it/21440#21440). But kinda the opposite of this question. :) Not answering the other one as of yet, because while I know this is how Canon hotshoes work, I can't figure out if it's how Nikon ones work, and there's also an issue of [loose hotshoes](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/52091386).

Comment: @inkista I thought we had a loose hotshoe question here in the past. Maybe I saw it somewhere else.

Comment: But the question referenced in my first comment above is this one: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/why-is-the-on-camera-flash-trying-to-pop-up-when-using-a-d7000-with-a-mk930-spee?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The Nikon internal flash is supposed to popup if camera is in Auto mode, anytime when the system thinks flash will be helpful.  It Never pop ups in camera A, S, P, or M modes, where the user opens the flash door to use flash, and user does not open door if not wanting flash (user control).

But Auto mode pops open the flash.  However it should not popup if it detects a hot shoe flash in place.  However, the Yongnuo YN560 (not capable of TTL) is possibly not CLS compatible, communication wise (there would be no point of it for opertating the flash, since the flash is Manual).  The camera probably is unaware of the manual YN560 presence (the camera would be very aware of any iTTL flash, they must communicate via the hot shoe pins).

So use camera A, S, P, or M  for flash with the popup.

YN560 cannot do TTL, but FWIW, flash TTL is still automatic flash even in camera Manual mode.

Realize that Auto mode is auto everything, no user control.

Camera P mode is auto exposure (of ambient), but is NOT Auto ISO or Auto White Balance, unless you have set those on yourself.  Nor auto color profile either (like Vivid).  The user sets stuff in A, S, P, or M modes.

Answer (score 0):

I would check how your YN-560 is seated on the flash hotshoe. Inside the rails of your camera's hotshoe, there should be a physical switch that tells the camera when an external flash is mounted, and this should prevent the pop-up flash from popping up.  If the camera isn't getting that signal, the switch could be stuck or broken, or your flash may not be seated all the way forward in the shoe.